# Login validator class

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, vb.net, authentication

I'm trying to learn more about object oriented programming and I have a few questions about the class below.
I'm working in Visual Basic.NET

My questions are

1. Is there a better place / way to show the `MessageBox.Show`?
2. I'm being forced to use a single Oracle Connection, in my sample `cnn` is declared with Friend scope so the entire solution can see it.  Is there a better way to handle this Connection Object, perhaps I should pass it all about my app as a parameter?
3. The `Sub SaveJobInfo` I put this in a Sub so it wouldn't clutter up the `ValidateLoginInfo` code, was wondering if there is a better way to check for Nulls other than using the `.Size` property?
4. Any other ideas that can improve this code?

```
Public Class LoginValidator

    Friend Shared Function ValidateLoginInfo(jobNum As String, userID As String, ByRef djnInfo As JobNumInfo) As Boolean
        Try

            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand() With {.Connection = cnn, .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, .CommandText = "owner.packageName.procedureName"}

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param1", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, jobNum, ParameterDirection.Input))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param2", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, userID, ParameterDirection.Input))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param3", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, My.Computer.Name.ToUpper, ParameterDirection.Input))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param3b", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, DJN_LOCK_ID, ParameterDirection.Input))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param4", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param5", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param6", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param7", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10000, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param8", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param9", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param10", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param11", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param12", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("param13", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1500, String.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output))

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            SaveJobInfo(djnInfo, cmd)

            For Each p As OracleParameter In cmd.Parameters
                p.Dispose()
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred in LoginValidator.ValidateLoginInfo" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, msgCaption)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True

    End Function

    Private Shared Sub SaveJobInfo(ByVal djnInfo As JobNumInfo, ByVal cmd As OracleCommand)

        If cmd.Parameters(4).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.UserAccessLevel = cmd.Parameters(4).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.UserAccessLevel = String.Empty
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(5).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.HasChildren = cmd.Parameters(5).Value.ToString.ToUpper = "YES"
        Else
            djnInfo.HasChildren = False
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(6).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.IsReleased = cmd.Parameters(6).Value.ToString.ToUpper = "YES"
        Else
            djnInfo.IsReleased = False
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(7).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.SpecInfo = cmd.Parameters(7).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.SpecInfo = String.Empty
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(8).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.OrgCode = cmd.Parameters(8).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.OrgCode = String.Empty
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(9).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.UOMFromOra = cmd.Parameters(9).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.UOMFromOra = String.Empty
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(10).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.DrawingNumber = cmd.Parameters(10).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.DrawingNumber = String.Empty
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(11).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.ProductRevisionCode = cmd.Parameters(11).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.ProductRevisionCode = String.Empty
        End If

        If cmd.Parameters(12).Size > 0 Then
            djnInfo.FirstArticleFamCode = cmd.Parameters(12).Value.ToString
        Else
            djnInfo.FirstArticleFamCode = String.Empty
        End If
        ' param 13 will be handled differently than the others
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I've removed the fluff you added to the end of your answer. If you have something to ask, ask it in the comments of the answer.

Comment: I had about 4 more 'fluffs' i was going to add to this original question so I could could use the formatting.  Would it make more sense to make new questions for my other 'fluffs'?

Comment: As long as your new question contains working, non-hypothetical code that you want reviewed, then ask away! :-)

Comment: It would be nice if I could keep it all in one question.  I'm not sure how to add to this question and have the option to 'format' my fluff additions?

Comment: Please just ask a new question. It's easier for everyone on the site, and it doesn't invalidate answers.

Answer (score 5):

- My first impression is that this class is doing too much. It is calling the database and manipulating the user interface. This needs to be separated.
- Exceptions are being swallowed and shown to the user, and a boolean value is returned.

  If an exception gets thrown in code calling to the database, let the exception bubble up. This is a catastrophic problem. If validating the login info is throwing an exception, write the database code so that it returns a flag if someone's login info isn't correct. [Don't use exceptions for flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control).
- The `ValidateLoginInfo` method calls `SaveJobInfo`. After validating login info, you shouldn't be saving data to the database. That should be a separate operation.
- I'm also questioning why you need to explicitly dispose of the OracleParameter objects. The CLR should clean those up just fine on its own.
- The `SaveJobInfo` method is confusing. It's taking stored procedure parameter values and mapping them to a `JobInfo` object? This should be done after validating the login info. The stored procedure you are calling has a lot of output parameters. The validation of login info and loading data into the JobInfo object should be two separate calls. One does not have anything to do with the other.

@Rose commented:

> If I changed the Exception handling and Caught any exceptions and simply Threw them back to whatever was calling ValidateLoginInfo, would this meet the 'bubbling up' definition?

If you are doing this:

```
Try
    // ...
Catch ex As Exception
    throw ex
End Try
```

Then there is no point in using a `Try-Catch`. Just execute the code and let the exceptions fly.

By "let the exception bubble up" I mean "don't use a `Try-Catch` if you can't recover from the exception." Unless your `ValidateLoginInfo` catches an exception and can recover from it, don't catch exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I really appreciate it.  

In regards to an exception being thrown in the code calling to the database and letting the exception 'bubble up'. . .  Please see edit to original question.  If I changed the Exception handling and Caught any exceptions and simply Threw them back to whatever was calling ValidateLoginInfo, would this meet the 'bubbling up' definition?